# JNI error: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass: name or signature does not match

Tags: java, java-native-interface, aop, aspectj

```
java/lang/NoSuchMethodError:
  Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class;
  name or signature does not match
```

See the following picture:

[image: Error message]

After adding org.aspectj dependency, everything is OK, but what is the reason?

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be kind enough to provide some feedback to the people who are trying to help you. Accept an answer if it solves your problem. Ask follow-up questions in comments, if there is something you do not understand about an answer. Saying nothing is simply not very polite.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the more interesting part of your stack trace is:

```
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
```

The reason is that (at least part of) your code has been compiled with the AspectJ compiler. In order for AspectJ to work, you need the AspectJ runtime on your classpath. So far, so simple.

BTW, if you want to use AspectJ 1.8.x for Java 8 support, 1.8.13 would be the most recent pre-Java-9 version. But you can also use 1.9.x, such as 1.9.7 (Java 16) or even 1.9.8.RC3 (Java 17), both of which should still be fully compatible with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for Java 1.8.0.262-ga, that particular overload for `Unsafe.defineClass` no longer exists.  It was previously deprecated and by 262 it had been removed entirely.

Presumably the version of the AspectJ runtime you were using previously was using the removed overload.  The version you are now is presumably more recent ... and no longer uses the removed overload.